# Organize WordPress site, so it can maintain with huge database

Tags: custom-post-types, database, capabilities, server-load, taxonomy

### Intro:

Hello, I am making coupon website and I need an advise. So, the structure at the moment is like this:

1. Coupons ( posts )
2. Categories of coupons  ( categories )
3. Shops ( tags )

In the near future my database will consist of approximately ~5000 shops ( tags ) and ~20000 coupons ( posts ) and also ~10000 of categories of coupons ( cats ). I will also add deals to website soon, so this might be also taken into consideration.

### The question:

What is the best way to organize such website, so it will work flawlessly after such huge amount of entries in database? Should I use **Custom Post Types** for any of my taxonomies? 
Thank you

Comment: As coupons will be related to a shop, how about using Shops as categories or another taxonomy? Use tags for its generic purposes or for coupon categories. However, the numbers you've mentioned will not be matter to worry for the database.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/55749/12615

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom Post Types are more convinient and easy to implement, so I suggest you use them. 
Also the Posts will be ready to make a blog section in the future.

About optimizing.

1. Use some caching plugin, there are lots of them in [Wordpress Plugin Directory](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=cache).
2. Turn off the revisions to save database size: add `define ('WP_POST_REVISIONS', 0);` into wp-config.php
3. And try to use as less plugins as possible. Only what you really need.

Comment: Thank you for advice about turning off revisions. That might be helpful.