# Stress testing WordPress

Tags: cms, server-load, bulk-import, performance

We are going to launch a community site with 100K posts, 100K comments, 10K terms, 5 users ( all admin/editorial), and approx 500K recs in the wp_postmeta.

Site may grow with a larger author base and we hope it will grow to become a much bigger site...

At this time, I would like to know how would WordPress behave when the above numbers reach the 10 times the current fold, that is

1M posts, 
1M comments, 
100K terms, 
500 users, 
and approx 5M recs in the wp_postmeta.

What tools can I use to put this many records into a WordPress install?

My migration routine takes about 10 hours to complete to put 100K posts into WP.
I must find more efficient ways to 1M records!

I know WP can handle fairly large database content and WordPress.com is the greatest example for that. However, those guys have of a ton of servers... In my case, I have what I have.

I'm curious to see/experience how the admin dashboard would load and how the front page ( with multiple loops ) behave...

Any ideas/tools towards this goal is greatly appreciated...

Of course, once I have that many recs, I will be needing a stress testing tool but I think I can find utilities for that.

We are using IIS 7 and we cannot switch to LINUX for legacy code reasons anytime soon.

Comment: Maybe sharing some replies here would be useful... [wp-hackers : Stress testing WordPress](http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2012-June/043326.html)

Answer (score 3):

Wordpress should behave the same, only dependent on your server resources. I hope you have a dedicated server because if not then you will experience severe outages and possibly cancellation of your hosting service.

Wordpress is merely databases and PHP, so amount of files will not affect its use. It is stable. You could have a billion or trillion or quadrillion of everything, it wouldn't matter, as long as you have the server resources to suffice.

p.s. where are you getting all this?

Comment: It's all about SQL work. When WordPress inserts/deletes records, obviously the speed of that operation would be dependend on the # of records. If you put 'quadrillion' posts into the wp_posts, you may simply assume that nothing gets to be served.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [load testing tool like Loadzen.com](http://loadzen.com/about/how-it-works/), it features a chrome plugin that will let you parameterise your form post requests so you can easily start populating your site with data while also putting the application under increasing user load (using mixed behaviour scenarios), it's a pay-as-you-go tool so you should be able to get started with the free tier.